# persist values from read-only properties in FileHelpers

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Is there a way that [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net) stores any read-only property?

I supposed there would be a solution using a[FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net) field attribute, but such an attribute does not seem exist. (Just the opposite one called [FieldHidden](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_FieldHiddenAttribute.htm) attribute exists).

The situation (code) is as follows

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public class MigrationFlags
{
    public const string HostUrlTemplate = "{HostUrl}";
    public MigrationFlags()
    {
    }

    [FieldHidden]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [FieldCaption("RelativeUrl " + HostUrlTemplate)]
    public string RelativeUrl => UriExt.GetRelativeUrl(this.Url);
```

Here I need to add the RelativeUrl.

It appeared  to me to use a converter on the Url property also, but is it possible to use a different solution where I can benefit from that already existing property named RelativeUrl?

Comment: I originally wanted to use it only in a scenario when to write to a text file, now I realise I would need also to read from the file, so it seems that, the solution usin a convertor will be better. So I am sorry for posting the question, but still I am curious the e.g. solution throug a field attribute (in that original one direction scenario) works ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend using the FileHelpers class for anything other than specifying the CSV file's format. The class represents one record in that file. Think of the syntax of your `MigrationFlags` class as a clever way of describing a record that FileHelpers can read and write automatically.

If you need to do add *any* further logic, it should be in a separate class that you map to/from as necessary. This separates the concerns - `MigrationFlags` defines the CSV record.

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public class MigrationFlags
{   
    // Extremely simple class.
    // Only the fields in the CSV
    // No logic. Nothing clever.
    public string RelativeUrl { get; set;};
}

public class MigrationClass
{   
    // A normal C# class with:
    //   constructors
    //   properties
    //   methods
    //   readonly, if you like
    //   inheritance, overrides, if you like
    // etc.

    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string RelativeUrl => UriExt.GetRelativeUrl(this.Url);
}
```

Then to export, something like:

```
public void Export(IEnumerable<MigrationClass> items, string filename)
{ 
    var migrationFlags = items.Select(
        x => new MigrationFlags() 
           { 
             RelativeUrl = x.RelativeUrl,
             // etc.
           });

    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<MigrationFlags>();
    engine.WriteFile(filename, migrationFlags);
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27148081/1077279) for more information.

Comment: Agreed. FileHelpers classes should have one purpose only, to define the file structure. They should contain no code. I found that even adding access modifiers to properties can break the FileHelpers engine. I even think the FH classes should not be publicly visible.